# How to display dates betwwen particular range in fullcalendar jQuery?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to show month view or dates between two dates, for example `2016-03-24` and `2016-04-25`. The calendar that loads the dates between these two dates will be bind on full calendar jQuery. How can I implement this?

Comment: check this url http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: You can set  start  : '2016-03-24', end    : '2016-04-25' for the event

Comment: hi, thnx for reply,actually i have a date range between  start date is '2016-03-24' and '2016-04-25' and between these two dates i have some events on different dates, what i try do is when calendar bind it will display events on give date but i just want to show calendar between these two dates.

Answer (score 1):

In the options object of your calendar you can make a custom view with the amount of days you want to show like this:

```
views: {
    customView: {
        type: 'agendaDay',
        duration: {days: 2}
        buttonText: 'custom'
    }
}
```

Now by setting [`defaultDate`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/defaultDate/) and [`firstDay`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/firstDay/) you can make it start on the desired day.

Once the calendar is rendered you can't change the properties of `customView` anymore, you will have to call `.fullCalendar('destroy')` and then reinitialise it with the new settings if you want to change the timespan.

---

The above was just a concept, [fiddle here](http://jsbin.com/xalayehuvu/edit?js,output). It is not possible to have the month view start on a specified date, so we work around this by setting the customView duration to 4 weeks (this is slightly different then 1 month)

```
views: {
    customView: {
        type: 'basicWeek',  
        duration: {week: 4},
        buttonText: 'customMonth'
    }
},
defaultDate: '2016-03-24',
firstDay: 4,
```

We also have to set the `defaultDate` property to let it start on the date we want and `firstDay` so it doesn't start on sunday. (this is easily done with moment by calling `moment().day()`)

Comment: Hi thanks, its for agenda, but i am looking for in month view.

Comment: `month view or dates between two dates`, which one of the two do you want ?

Comment: hi Thanks for reply, i just want to show calendar between '2016-03-24' to '2016-04-25' in a month view.